# Echo message based on row number in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table which displays information from a database. I added a column where I want to display a message according to row number displayed.

```
<form name="afisare1" method="POST" >
    <input type="submit" name="opt1"  value="OK"/>
    <?php   
     if (isset($_POST['opt1'])) {
        $loc=mysql_query("SELECT loc FROM program WHERE den='Option'");
        //$loc result is a number

        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT Col1, Col2 
                          FROM date WHERE Opt_1='Option' OR Opt_2='Option' 
                          ORDER BY Col2 DESC");
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Col1</th> <th>Col2</th> <th>OK/NOT OK</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        $num_rows = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $num_rows++;
            if ($num_rows <= $loc) {
                echo"<tr>
                        <td>".$row['Col1']."</td><td >".$row['Col2']."</td><td>OK</td>
                     </tr>";
                break;
            } 
            if ($num_rows > $locuri_buget) { 

                //here i have a problem because i don't know how to display something like this : 
                //echo"<tr><td>".$row['Col1']."</td><td >".$row['Col2']."</td><td>NOT OK</td></tr>";   
            }
        }
    }  ?>
    </table>    
</form>
```

For example if the result of $loc=2 i want to echo for the first 2 rows OK and for extra rows i want to echo NOT OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve `loc` from MySQL, your original code does it like this:

```
$loc = mysql_query("SELECT loc FROM program WHERE den='Option'");
```

But you might want to change it like this:

```
$loc = 0; # default value in case of error in a query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT loc FROM program WHERE den='Option'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $loc = $row['loc'];
}
```

Or if you want retrieve only one record from your databse, you can also write a SQL with `LIMIT` like this:

```
$loc = 0; # default value in case of error in a query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT loc FROM program WHERE den='Option' LIMIT 1");
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $loc = $row['loc'];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following inside while loop

```
if($num_rows<=$loc){
 echo"<tr><td>".$row['Col1']."</td><td >".$row['Col2']."</td><td>OK</td></tr>";
}else{ 
 echo"<tr><td>".$row['Col1']."</td><td >".$row['Col2']."</td><td>NOT OK</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: This will echo for all rows OK.

Comment: will echo 'OK' for $num_rows<=$loc and 'Not OK' only for $num_rows>$loc

Comment: Thank you but the problem wasn't here. The problem was the way to retrieve $loc.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $num_rows = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $num_rows++;
     if($num_rows<=$loc){
           echo"<tr><td>".$row['Col1']."</td><td >".$row['Col2']."</td><td>OK</td></tr>";
      }else {  
           echo"<tr><td>".$row['Col1']."</td><td >".$row['Col2']."</td><td>OK</td></tr>";
      }
 }
```

I think your problem is with break,

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.
>   [Break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Comment: If i don't use break, will echo OK for all rows